# Inputted values from textfield to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem creating a solution to this problem:

Create an app that will store 5 numbers (preferrably float) and then sort them out.The array type is immutable.

First off: My problem is how to get the floats from the textfield then put it into a array. My idea is to code it like this:

```
int a = [num1.text intValue];
int b = [num2.text intValue];
int c = [num3.text intValue];

NSArray *myArray;
myArray = [NSArray stringWithFormat: @"%f",a,b,c];
```

My second problem is that I can't understand how to sort the floats. Will you please give me some idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    CGFloat a = [num1Label.text floatValue];
    CGFloat b = [num2Label.text floatValue];
    CGFloat c = [num3Label.text floatValue];
    CGFloat d = [num4Label.text floatValue];
    CGFloat e = [num5Label.text floatValue];

    NSArray *array = @[ [NSNumber numberWithFloat:a],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:b],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:c],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:d],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:e]];

    array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // logic for sorting
        NSNumber *number1 = (NSNumber *)obj1;
        NSNumber *number2 = (NSNumber*)obj2;

        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```

CGFloat is basically the same as float.

If you check the Documentation (OPTION + Click on that), you see this:

```
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float

// ...

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

CG comes from Core Graphics.

float comes from C/C++

It is more recommended to use CGFloat in Objective-C, instead of simply float. Also, NSInteger instead of int.

Comment: Hey there dude! thanks for the reply! can I ask you what does the CGFloat means?

Comment: one last question dude, (so sorry) will you explain to me how the sorting goes? thank you very much

Comment: It is simple, the sortedArrayUsingComparator: method will use the NSComparisonResult block logic in its algorithm, which does everything on your behalf. The line "return [first compare:second];" uses the compare: method of the NSNumber class, which detects how to compare the 2 numbers based on their type. The algorithm itself may be pretty complex to understand for you. You can google for QuickSort, which is one of the most efficient sorting methods. Other methods are MergeSort, SelectSort, BubbleSort(the worst) etc.

Comment: I have one last question sir :) should I put the other objects like obj3,obj 4,obj 5 in the sortedArrayUsingComparator?
or it is constant to only have two  objects

Comment: No, only 2 id objects as parameters, this is a NSArray method/block from the iOS SDK precompiled Foundation framework. To better understand, it asks you the way you want to compare 2 objects in the array (so it would no how to put them in order), but those objects can be of any type: NSDate, NSNumber, NSDictionary, even custom of classes like Person etc. Check the Apple Docs for more details and other ways to sort collections: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html